# Lookup or Link Items in separate lists

Tags: lookup-column

I'm new to this site and to SharePoint and need a bit of help.

I'm using SP2013. I have a list that has item numbers and the person assigned to each item. I would like to know how to link other lists in the site so that when I have the item# in a different list the person will populate.

Basically, if this was excel I would be doing a vlookup from one workbook to another.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Parent child relationship lists.

List 1

ItemNumber - Single line of text
Person - Person and Group.

List 2
Title - Single line of text.

ItemNumber - Lookup column(from List 1, Column to be selected ItemNumber)
Also in this page, you can select which all columns from List1 you need to bring as supporting data. Here you can select Person Column.